# Read data from Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using this code:

```
exports.lotteryTickets = functions.database.ref('/lottery/ticketsneedstobeprocessed/{randomID}').onWrite(event => {
    let ticketsBoughtByUser = event.data.val();

})
```

But ticketsBoughtByUser is not correct. How can I retrieve the the number shown in the picture below, so next to the string (oeb...)? Thank you.

[image]

I get this log:[image]

Comment: How are you seeing that it's NaN?  You're showing just one line of code right now inside your function, so it's impossible to see what's really going on.

Comment: console.log(ticketsBoughtByUser), then I go to firebase functions and I see that log. It is the whole function. I just want to get "1", or any other integer that could appear there... Ofcourse the console log is after the declaration of let ticketsBoughtByUser.

Comment: I am sorry, NaN appeared when I tried this: Number(event.data.val();). However, I get the following log which I added in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, `event.data.val()` obviously doesn't return a number.  It returns an object, which you are seeing in the log.  You can actually see the data in the object if you `console.log(ticketsBoughtByUser)` (don't use string concatenation to build the message).

For the data you show in the database, I would expect the val to be an object that contains this data (redacted so I won't have to type it):

```
{
    "oeb...IE2": 1
}
```

If you want to get the `1` out of that object, you'd have to reach into it using the string key, whatever that string represents:

```
const num = ticketsBoughtByUser["oeb...IE2"]
```

If you want *just* the number and not the object at the location you originally gave, you will need two wildcards to get at it directly:

```
exports.lotteryTickets = functions.database
        .ref('/lottery/ticketsneedstobeprocessed/{randomID}/{whatIsThis}')
        .onWrite(event => {
    const num = event.data.val()
}
```

I added a wildcard for `whatIsThis`, which will match that string I redacted above.

But I don't really know what your function is trying to accomplish, so it's just speculation as to whether or not you should actually do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the ticketsBoughtByUser value like below

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/articles/{articleId}')
        .onWrite(event => {

        // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        var eventSnapshot = event.data;

       //Here You can get value through key
        var str = eventSnapshot.child("author").val();

        console.log(str);

        });
```